# How to get oauthConsumerkey and oauthConsumerSecret of google app?

Tags: google-api, access-token, google-sheets-api

I am trying to create a connector for Google spreadsheet. So that I try to create an app in Google developer console, After that how can I get  oauthConsumerkey and oauthConsumerSecret from it? Are there any links or guidance to explain it? videos or websites? I have refer some Google sites, But I'm unable to get clear information from it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

- On The developer console (https://console.developers.google.com), click on Create Project.
- Click on APIs & auth on the left hand side menu to enable APIs (this isn't required for spreadsheets)

  - A new button should appear in the left hand side menu 'Credentials'
  - Click on Create new Client ID

This will provide you with the ClientID, Client Secret and Email Address. Set Redirect URIs and Javascript Origins as required by your application.

You will also need an API key, which is generated by clicking on the 'Create new Key' button beneath the OAuth section.

In order to allow users to login from your application, you can use http://www.accountchooser.com. Which is farely easy to use and allows for various identities.

Comment: I asked that how to get oauthConsumerkey and oauthConsumerSecret?

Comment: My answer explains how to retrieve ALL that is required for oauth from developer console.

Comment: So do you know how to get oauthConsumerkey and oauthConsumerSecret?

Comment: It translates to client id, client secret

Comment: Consumerkey and Client Id are same or not??